# How can I read all current processes and print them in console? / C# ConsoleApp System.Diagnostics

Tags: c#, visual-studio, process, system.diagnostics

I got this error:

(I can give more info from inspector)

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'access denied'
>
> The exception was originally generated in this call stack:
>
> System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.OpenProcess(int, int, bool)
>
> System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessHandle(int, bool)
>
> System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessTimes()
>
> System.Diagnostics.Process.StartTime.get()
>
> ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(string[]) on Program.cs

There is the code:

(I was running this program as administrator since the beginning)

**The correct answer is how to ignore exceptions, because the error occurs because certain processes cannot be read even if you have administrator privileges**

```
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    
    
    class Program
    {
        public class Win32Exception : System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException
        {

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var moment = DateTime.Now;
                String rh = moment.Hour.ToString();
                String rm = moment.Minute.ToString();
                String rs = moment.Second.ToString();

                Console.Title = moment.ToString("HH:mm:ss");


                Process[] localAll = Process.GetProcesses();
                /// Process[] procesos;
                ///procesos = Process.GetProcesses();
                ///


                foreach (Process p in localAll)
                {
                    /// Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName);
                    try
                    {
                        var tmp = p.StartTime;


                        String h = p.StartTime.ToString("HH");
                        String m = p.StartTime.ToString("mm");
                        String s = p.StartTime.ToString("ss");

                        int x = Int32.Parse(rh);
                        int y = Int32.Parse(h);


                        if (x <= y)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"{p.ProcessName} TIME= {p.StartTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss")}");

                        }
                    }
                    catch (Win32Exception)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }


                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Win32Exception is not working as i expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colud you try replace the catch exception as `Exception`?

```
catch (Exception)
   {
       continue;
   }
```

Another way if you want to mantain the `Win32Exception` is to change the inheritance of your custom exception to

```
public class Win32Exception : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare a class inheriting `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException`. You just need to use `try...catch` to catch the exception `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception`. Just modify the code like this.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Code omitted
        // ...
        // Code omitted
        foreach (Process p in localAll)
        {
            try
            {
                // Code omitted
                // ...
                // Code omitted
            }
            catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```